# Error:(43, 17) error: <identifier> expected (android studio)

Tags: java, android

In my main activity.java program, I cannot find the error properly can help me to find the error.

this is the that I was getting error.

```
package com.example.lahiru.myapplication1;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static Button group_sbm;
    private static Button courses_sbm;
    private static Button about_sbm;*strong text*
    private static Button Home_sbm;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button buttonPlayVedio2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button8);
        getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.UNKNOWN);

        VideoView mVideoVeiw2 = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView2);

        final String uriPath2 = "" + R.raw.vedio1;
        final uri ur12 = Uri.parse(uriPath2);
        mVideoView2.setVideoURI(uri12);
        mVideoView2.requesFocus();
        mVideoView2.start();

        buttonPlayVideo2.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnCliickListner()

        {
            @Override
            public void onclick(View v) {
                VideoView mVideoView2 = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView2);

            }

            ur12 =uri.parse(uriPath2);
        });
    }

    public void LoadHomePage() {
        Home_sbm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Home_sbm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.lahiru.myapplication1.MainActivity");
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    public void LoadCoursePage() {
        courses_sbm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        courses_sbm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.lahiru.myapplication1.Main3Activity");
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    public void LoadAboutUsPage() {
        group_sbm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
        group_sbm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.lahiru.myapplication1.Main2Activity");
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    public void LoadGroupPage() {
        about_sbm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
        about_sbm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.lahiru.myapplication1.Main2Activity");
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This what I getting displayed:

> Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
>   C:\Users\lahiru\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication1\app\src\main\java\com\example\lahiru\myapplication1\MainActivity.java
>   Error:(43, 17) error:  expected Error:Execution failed for
>   task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.> Compilation failed; see the
>   compiler error output for details. Information:BUILD FAILED in 2s
>   Information:2 errors Information:0 warnings Information:See complete
>   output in console

Comment: What is `uri` in `final uri ur12`? I think it should be URI.

Answer (score 0):

There is a compilation error online 43:

```
ur12 =uri.parse(uriPath2);
```

That line of code should not be inside the `Button.OnClickListener` block of code. It can be removed since it has already been done above around line 28.

There are also spelling errors. This will likely not compile either: `Button.OnCliickListner()`.